# finding objects in an ArrayList by String

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that contains Product objects. I am now trying to use a query method to find the products in the list by String name and String id. @ return I need a Product [ ].

```
public Product [] findProducts(Lookup query)
    {
        int count = 0;``
        Product [] products = productsList.toArray(new Product[MAX_PRODUCTS]);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nextProduct; ++i)
        {
            if (query.matches(this.products[i]))
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        Product [] selected = new Product[count];
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nextProduct; ++i)
        {
            if (query.matches(this.products[i]))
            {
                selected[count++] = this.products[i];
            }
        }

        return selected;
    }
```

I first converted the ArrayList into an Array, then tried to traverse and find the matches.

Comment: seems to me `products` is defined but never used. please elaborate...

Comment: OK, so what's wrong with what you have? What does it do? We can't know what `this.nexProduct` is.

Comment: so this is an assignment and I can not change the signature in the method. this was from an older assignment that worked with arrays. the objective now is to transform the array into an arraylist. unfortunately, i am not allowed to change the what the method returns(Product [ ])

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID and name are unique values, you can develop these two functions below for searching purposes:

```
Product FindByID (int id, Product [] p) {
    for(int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
       if(p[i].Id == id)
          return p[i];
    }
    return null;
}

Product FindByName (String name, Product [] p) {
    for(int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
       if(p[i].Name.Equals(name))
          return p[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can use the functions above like:

```
Product p = FindByID(10);
```

Here, if p is not null, then you found the item..

Comment: why do you throw an exception where no product is found even though it’s not actually an error?. a better option would be to return an `Optional<Product>` but yet I don't think the OP has provided enough context for one to pinpoint their current problem. Also, doesn't the OP want a `Product []` as the return type?

Comment: They're wanting a `Product[]` to be returned so I don't think returning just the first one will work.

Comment: I would return just null actually, thought the OP might want to know where the problem is, but I will update now @Aominè

Answer (score 0):

A stream should allow filtering and collection to an array quite quickly:

```
productsList.stream()
            .filter(p -> query.matches(p))
            .toArray(Product[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna filter use Stream. Work with List are easier than Array as well

```
List<Product> result = input.stream() //your product input list
    .filter(product -> "XYZ".equals(product.name)) 
    .filter(product -> 1.equals(product.id)) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```